# Set Image Custom Field as Open Graph Image in Metatags

Tags: meta-tags

I have installed the Metatags module along with the Open Graph and Twitter Card extension modules. In my default content type, I have added an Image field that allows an image to be uploaded for use on Facebook and Twitter.

Now I cannot get the Metatags module to accept this image custom field as the entry for the og:image and Twitter Card Image fields. I've tried entering [node:field_image] but the meta tags do not get added to the source code. If I enter a URL the tags appear.

How do I get Metatags to dynamically include a corresponding image for each page in the Open Graph and Twitter Cards metadata?

Answer (score 3):

I used `drupal_add_html_head` in my case. In my theme template.php.

```
$og_image = image_style_url('200x200', $node->field_gallery_preview_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']);
// OG image meta property.
drupal_add_html_head(array(
  '#tag' => 'meta',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'property' => 'og:image',
    'content' => $og_image,
  ),
), 'node_' . $node->nid . '_og_image');
```

Comment: How to add og image for users??? replace node with users?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed editing my template.php > MYTHEME_html_head_alter.

Code:

```
function YOURTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  // Overwrite og:image file
  $head_elements['opengraph_meta_og:image']['#attributes']['content'] = "path/to/your/image.jpg" ;
 }
```